# Rspec: Selecting a radio button for Sinatra form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, sinatra

I am writing test specs for a Sinatra app. How can I ask rspec to click on a radio button in my form?

```html
<form action="/reports/new" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="radios">Borough</label>
      <div>
          <label>
            <input name="Brooklyn" id="borough_1" value="1" type="radio">Brooklyn</input>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input name="Bronx" id="borough_2" value="2" type="radio">Bronx</input>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input name="Manhattan" id="borough_3" value="3" type="radio">Manhattan</input>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input name="Queens" id="borough_4" value="4" type="radio">Queens</input>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input name="Staten Island" id="borough_5" value="5" type="radio">Staten Island</input>
          </label>
        <button value="Submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Edit: I did check out this resource but it didn't help me: [stackoverflow.com/questions/11483967/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483967/%E2%80%A6) I tried `choose('Manhattan')`. However, i keep getting this error: `Failure/Error: choose('Manhattan') Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find radio button "Manhattan"`

Good news is that rspec is at least looking for a radio button.

```html
        visit '/reports/new'
        fill_in(:title, :with => "Ben and Jerries Ice Cream")
        fill_in(:business, :with => "Starbucks")
        fill_in(:location, :with => "146 Rikers Street")
        fill_in(:content, :with => "Some great food")
        fill_in(:date, :with => "2016-09-12")
        choose('Manhattan')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430074/how-to-click-radio-button-with-capybara-in-ruby-on-rails-app) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483967/selecting-a-radio-button-with-rspec) [available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085057/capybara-chooseradio-button-not-working) with a quick google search; have you researched and experimented with these?

Comment: I did check out this resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483967/selecting-a-radio-button-with-rspec?noredirect=1&lq=1

I tried `choose('Manhattan')`. However, i keep getting this error:
```Failure/Error: choose('Manhattan')
     
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find radio button "Manhattan"```

Comment: @Joel B, please add the details of your last comment to your question, it will help us in the future.

Comment: Are you sure Capybara is looking at the right url? Are you using Capybara's visit method before the choose method, or something similar?

Comment: I updated my post to show what my spec looks like. There are a few more input fields for strings above the radio buttons. Before any forms are filled in or radio buttons are pressed I `visit 'reports/new'` which has the form in question. I have some other forms that I can successfully fill in with Rspec. Not sure if I need to target the "name", "id" or "value" portions of the tag

Comment: It looks like you're doing it right. When you go to 'reports/new' in your browser, open up a javascript console and do $('#borough_3'); you should find it. Worth double checking?

Comment: choose will find by name or id, doesn't matter.

Comment: ^^ That is good to know that it finds by name or id. I understand now that all the radio buttons have to have the same name, but they can have different ID's.

Comment: @eeeeeean, finally got it working. The info about rspec looking for ID or Name was extremely helpful. if you leave an answer here somewhere i will mark it as answered. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`choose` finds things by **id**, **name** or **label**. From the docs:

> #**choose**([locator], options) ⇒ Object
>
> Find a radio button and mark it as checked. The radio button can be
>   found via name, id or label text.

Make sure that: a) Capybara is going to 'reports/new' and b) that your page is rendering those elements as expected. For example, try going to 'reports/new' yourself and selecting that element in the console (assuming you have jQuery) with:

```
$('#borough_3');
```

Or just look for it in the source.